# Direct summands of direct sum of line bundles on projective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Serre-Swan's theorem (see the [MO discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36286/holomorphic-vector-bundles-and-swans-theorem)) says that any locally free sheaf over an affine variety is a direct summand of a free sheaf. However, this is not true on projective varieties. It is not hard to check that a non-trivial line bundle with non-zero global sections can not be a direct summand of a free sheaf. The reason is that, being a direct summand of a free sheaf implies that the dual line bundle also has non-zero global sections. But that implies the line bundle is trivial.

I am wondering if the same holds for vector bundles, i.e. if a vector bundle and its dual over a projective variety both have non-zero global sections, then the vector bundle is trivial.

Another I think related question is the following:

Is a direct summand of a direct sum of line bundles on a projective variety also a direct sum of line bundles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) The vector bundle $E=\mathcal O(1) \oplus \mathcal O(-1)$ over $\mathbb P^1$ has non trivial sections and so has its dual (which happens to be the same bundle $E$ ).
 However  $E$ is non trivial  because each of its global sections has a zero.

2) Yes, a direct summand of a direct sum of line bundles *on a complete variety* is also a direct sum of line bundles.
This follows from [Atiyah's general version of the Krull-Schmidt theorem](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/BSMF/BSMF_1956__84_/BSMF_1956__84__307_0/BSMF_1956__84__307_0.pdf) .

**Edit**
Since Fei asks, let me remark that the trick in 1) works also for bundles which are not direct sums of line bundles:
If $T$ is the tangent bundle to $\mathbb P^2$, then $E=T \oplus T^* $ has non-trivial global sections , and so has  $E^*=E$
However, since $T$ is indecomposable   $E$  is not a sum of line bundles by Atiyah's result and is thus *a fortiori* not trivial.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. For the first question, do you have a counterexample that $E$ is not a direct sum of line bundles?

Comment: Dear @Fei,yes:  I have added such a counterexample in an Edit.

Comment: Dear George, Thank you so much for the example. I saw you used a fact $E^\ast=E$ for $E=T\oplus T^\ast$. Is there are general relation between $E$ and $E^\ast$. I saw somewhere that $E^\ast\otiems \det(E)=E$. Is this really true in general? Thanks again for you help!

Comment: Dear @Fei, I have just used that the dual of  a direct sum is the direct sum of the duals. The formula you quote is already false for every non trivial line bundle   $L$ since $L^* \otimes det(L)=L^* \otimes L$ *is* trivial.

Comment: Dear Georges. Thank you very much for your patience. This is a very quick counterexample. In fact, I should have asked for higher rank vector bundles, say rank$E$$\geq2$.  What I was thinking is that for rank$E$=2, it could be true that $E^\ast\otimes det(E)\cong E$. But for higher rank it should be false.

Comment: Dear @Fei, yes, for rank $2$ it is correct: Hartshorne, Ex.II 5.16